# How to get checkbox in the DataGridTemplateColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I'm creating a window for user delete multiple registers of database using `DataGrid` for show data and a `Button` for execute delete

So I putted a `DataGridTemplateColumn` in the `DataGrid` and `CheckBox` in this `DataGridTemplateColumn`

```
<DataGrid Name="WordList" Margin="10" Width="230" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="WordList_SelectionChanged" 
            CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Name="WordChecked" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Word}" Header="Word" Width="1*" 
            IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Please, how to can I access this CheckBox with C# for check it is checked or not?

Comment: Add a bool property to the Model and bint to the CheckBox, then you can query your collection

Comment: Have somehow for access this Cell in all rows?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I argue something like this doesn't belong in the model because it has nothing to do with the domain. I think a better approach is putting an event on the checkbox that adds the currently selected datagrid item to a List that resides in the ViewModel, then the button deletes from that list.

Comment: @Jim I liked your idea, but how to can I get row index of CheckBox for save a List?

Comment: When you click the checkbox for the row to be deleted, that should set the `Datagrid.SelectedItem`

Comment: It's working!! Thank you very much! this solution is so easy for development!

Comment: Sure thing, I'll move the comments to an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommended approach is to have a `List<Item>` that is held in the ViewModel and whenever you check the `CheckBox` in the row the datagrid's `SelectedItem` will be set and you add the item that was selected to the `List`. Then when the button is clicked, you delete all the records that are in the `List`.

Ideally you also want to implement this using `Command`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked= "{Binding checked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

```
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   int index = DGItems.SelectedIndex;
   DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)DGItems.Items[index];
}
```